# How do I retrieve all subscribers that have been modified since a given time?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I'm trying query [Subscriber](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/subscriber/) with a simple filter that checks if the property `ModifiedDate` is greater than a given timestamp, but I'm getting this error:

```
Error: The Filter Property 'ModifiedDate' is not a retrievable property.
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is there another endpoint like SubscriberList or ListSubscriber that is more appropriate for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve the ListSubscriber object. I created a ComplexFilter where I am filtering on ModifiedDate and ListID, where ListID is the ID of my All Subscribers list. If you don't filter on ListID you may get multiple results for a single email address if they are on different lists.

Here is the SOAP envelope I used to do this:

```
<ns1:Body>
  <ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
    <ns0:RetrieveRequest>
      <ns0:ObjectType>ListSubscriber</ns0:ObjectType>
      <ns0:Properties>ListID</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>SubscriberKey</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>Status</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Filter xsi:type="ns0:ComplexFilterPart">
        <ns0:LeftOperand xsi:type="ns0:SimpleFilterPart">
          <ns0:Property>ModifiedDate</ns0:Property>
          <ns0:SimpleOperator>greaterThan</ns0:SimpleOperator>
          <ns0:Value>2014-05-15</ns0:Value>
        </ns0:LeftOperand>
        <ns0:LogicalOperator>AND</ns0:LogicalOperator>
        <ns0:RightOperand xsi:type="ns0:SimpleFilterPart">
          <ns0:Property>ListID</ns0:Property>
          <ns0:SimpleOperator>equals</ns0:SimpleOperator>
          <ns0:Value>12345</ns0:Value>
        </ns0:RightOperand>
      </ns0:Filter>
    </ns0:RetrieveRequest>
  </ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
</ns1:Body>
```

If you don't know the ListID of you all subscribers list, you can get it through your ET account by logging in and viewing the properties on the All Subscribers list, or you can do this through the API. Here is envelope for retrieving ListID, filtering on ListName:

```
<ns1:Body>
  <ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
    <ns0:RetrieveRequest>
      <ns0:ObjectType>List</ns0:ObjectType>
      <ns0:Properties>ID</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Filter xsi:type="ns0:SimpleFilterPart">
        <ns0:Property>ListName</ns0:Property>
        <ns0:SimpleOperator>equals</ns0:SimpleOperator>
        <ns0:Value>All Subscribers</ns0:Value>
      </ns0:Filter>
    </ns0:RetrieveRequest>
  </ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
</ns1:Body>
```

Comment: did this actually run for you? Trying it now and I get status OK, but no other subscriber data